# How I can bind std::function of class1 to a func of class2?

Tags: c++, c++17

```
class foo {
public:
    std::function<void(int)> func;
};

class obj {
public:
    obj() { f.func = std::bind(&obj::update, this); }
    void update(int ms) { _ms = ms; }

private:
    int _ms;
    foo f;
};
```

I want bind a func of `obj` because when something occurs in `foo` the latter notify to other class without using an observer pattern.
Can someone help me to do this?

Comment: How is this code not working for you?

Comment: Did you read the [`bind()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) reference?

Comment: Just use a _lambda function_ instead of `std::bind`.

Comment: @NathanOliver i think he forgot to add std::placeholders when doing the std::bind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youre need add the placeholders, but std::bind is deprecated and will be removed in C++ 17 so don't use it. Modern C++ give us this solution:

```
class foo {
public:
    std::function<void(int)> func;
};

class obj {
public:
    obj() {
        f.func = [this](int arg)->void
        {
            update(arg);
        };
    }
    void update(int ms) { _ms = ms; }

private:
    int _ms;
    foo f;
};
```

I'm recommend you learn about lambda function and how work with them.

About std::bind deprecation 
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4190.htm
Article III What must die and we can see binders and functional object.

Comment: "std::bind is deprecated" -- [citation needed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citation_needed)

Comment: thank you, I prefered avoid `std::bind` if is deprecated, but capture `this` using `[=]` is deprecated in c++20 then I used `[this]` :D

Comment: i wasnt aware of std::bind getting deprecated. links please. could it be possible that you are confusing it with `std::bind1st`, `std::bind2nd` ?

Comment: I don't know if it's deprecated, but even if it's not, you should stop using it and replace it with lambdas.

Comment: so yes , probably i'm confuse std::bind with std::binders.

Answer (score 0):

Edit : Looking at your code, it seems that you missing the std::placeholders::_1 when you assigning the f.func to std::bind. doing the following should fix your problem.

```
obj() { f.func = std::bind(&obj::update, this, std::placeholders::_1); }
```

you can assign the function as follows but to be honest im not sure if this is a good idea if we were to pass it as std::ref. for this example i think it wouldn't cause issue since std::bind is using move but if `f` was not a member of `obj` and if it wa passed as reference then there would be a problem if `obj` gets destroyed before `f::func` is called.

```
class foo
{
public:
    void AssignFunc(std::function<void(int)> callback)
    {
        func  = callback;
        func(10);
    }

private:
    std::function<void(int)> func;
};

class obj {
public:
    obj()
    {
        f.AssignFunc(std::bind(&obj::update, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    }
    void update(int ms)
    {
        _ms = ms;
    }

private:
    int _ms;
    foo f;
};
```

Comment: thank you but i prefere avoid `bind` because is deprecated

Comment: can you guys share citation regards to std::bind beeing deprecated in c++17.

Comment: @F.Guerinoni that link just proves that the `std::bind` is an alternative just like lambdas for `std::bind1st, std::bind2nd` . i dont see anywhere it mentioned `std::bind` is deprecated 0.0'